# Java threads and applets

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, applet

The assignment was to simulate a 'race' with two runners represented with 1(red rectangle) 2 (blue rectangle). when I hit the start button I'm supposed to use threads to increment the width of the rectangle and the first one to reach the width of the screen is the winner. Everything works properly EXCEPT that for some unknown reason I cannot get these rectangles to appear.

HTML:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<APPLET CODE="AppletGame.class" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="400">
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

panel

```
//extends thread
//        thread contains the run(); method and sets rectangle specifics
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

 public class ThreadPanel extends JPanel
 {
//private Thread blueRunner =
private JLabel winnerLabel, gamelabel;
private int redWidth = 2, blueWidth = 2, x, y;
private JPanel board;
private Random generator = new Random();
private Thread RedRunner = new  RedRunner();
private Thread BlueRunner = new  BlueRunner();
  //Create a panel for the button and label
  //then create a pannel for the Rectangles(runners) to race
public ThreadPanel()
{
    winnerLabel = new JLabel ("Winner: ");
    winnerLabel.setBackground(Color.green);
    add(winnerLabel);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,360));
    setBackground (Color.white);
}

//graphics method to paint the shapes
public void PainComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //draws 2 seperate rectangles
    super.paintComponent(g);

    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(25, 100,redWidth, 2);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(25, 100, blueWidth, 2);
 }
    //begins game and starts two threads
   public void startGame ()
   {
     RedRunner.start();
     BlueRunner.start();
   }

//create the threads that contain the (run method)
//x is the red runner, y for blue (to get random numbers)
class RedRunner extends Thread
{
    public RedRunner(){
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(redWidth<=300)
        {
        x = generator.nextInt(6);
        redWidth+=x;
            if(redWidth==300 && blueWidth <300)
            {
            winnerLabel.setText("Winner: Red");
            }

        }
    }
}

//creates the second runner
class BlueRunner extends Thread
{
        public BlueRunner(){
        }

        public void run()
        {
          while(redWidth<300)
          {
          y = generator.nextInt(6);
          blueWidth+=y;
            if(redWidth<300 && blueWidth<300)
             {
                winnerLabel.setText( "Winner: Blue");
             }
          }

        }
}
}
```

and finally the class that extends JApplet:

```
 //#2
  //java file that extends JAPPLET which implements action listener
  //containts a button to start the game
  //containts instantiation of panel which contain the threads/runners
 //makes a rectangle object
  //IE constructs the objects
   import java.awt.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;

  public class AppletGame extends JApplet implements ActionListener
  {
//applet that simulates 2 runners
   private final int BOARDWIDTH = 300, BOARDHEIGHT =400;

   private JButton startPlay;
   private ThreadPanel game;
   private String red = "Red", blue = "Blue";
   private int hits=0;

   private JPanel appletPanel, buttons;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Set up the components for the applet
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
public void init()
{
    buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setOpaque(true);
    buttons.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOARDWIDTH, 40));
    buttons.setBackground(Color.white);

    startPlay = new JButton("Start Race");
    startPlay.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    startPlay.addActionListener(this);  //adds button listener for starting

    buttons.add(startPlay);

    game = new ThreadPanel();  //panel for the race portion of the applet

    appletPanel = new JPanel();
    appletPanel.add(buttons);//ands buttons and game panel to primary panel
    appletPanel.add(game);

    getContentPane().add(appletPanel);
      setSize(BOARDWIDTH, BOARDHEIGHT);     //sets size of primary panel

}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    String msg = "Race over Click to start again";
    if(event.getSource() == startPlay)
    {
        startPlay.setEnabled(false);
        game.startGame();
        repaint();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to spelling and capitalization. Notice you have:

```
public void PainComponent(Graphics g)
```

Should be:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

Comment: wow...Thank you. Sometimes it helps having someone else look over it